# add Email/Password provider even there's another provider using the email

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

My application have sign in methods like:

- 3rd party provider (Facebook, Google, Apple)
- Email/Password

There's a feature from the app where the user can switch to traditional login but they need to provide a Password for the account in order to continue.
This error always show whenever I'm calling the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` from the `FirebaseAuth` to create an `Email/Password` auth provider for the user that already exists but using different provider like Facebook etc.

`[firebase_auth/email-already-in-use] The email address is already in use by another account.`

How can I fix this error? Should I change something in my authentication flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing when you call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is trying to create an account that already exists. In FireBase it is possible to have a user who does not have a password and that is the situation you have.

Instead, I believe you need to use `User.updatePassword()` (https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/updatePassword.html)

Then you can use `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword()` to sign in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm confused on the part if I still need to create a new user if there's a new provider, in my case, the new provider was Email/Password.  One thing to also watch out or to handle is the exception of: requires-recent-login. Thanks Sylith!

Comment: You don't need to create a new user if the user already has an email linked to their account; it is sufficient to just update their password.

To avoid the exception 'requires-recent-login', you need to use the method `User.reauthenticateWithCredential()` (https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/reauthenticateWithCredential.html). One of its main purposes is to be called before sensitive operations such as update password. Hope that helps!